# How to set up apex:selectRadio in a grid layout

Tags: apex, visualforce, inline-visualforce, selectradio, slds-grid

I'm trying to achieve below layout.

[image]

Below is my code (with 2 approaches) on VF page.

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" applyHtmlTag="true" >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <apex:slds />

    <apex:form>
        <b>1st Approach</b><br/>

        <apex:selectRadio layout="PageDirection">
            <fieldset class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_compound">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__row">
                        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                            <div class="slds-form-element">
                                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" title="1st Radio button" itemLabel="test1"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" title="1st Radio button" itemLabel="test2"/>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                            <div class="slds-form-element">
                                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                    <input type="text" id="input-01" class="slds-input" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                    <input type="text" id="input-02" class="slds-input" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </apex:selectRadio>

        <br/><hr/><br/>

        <b>2nd Approach</b><br/>

        <apex:selectRadio layout="PageDirection">
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="option 3"/>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col"><apex:inputText styleClass="slds-input"/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col">
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="option 4"/> 
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col"><apex:inputText styleClass="slds-input"/></div>
            </div>

        </apex:selectRadio>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Resulting output as below:

[image: Resulting Page]

I'm trying to create this layout with < apex:selectRadio >. Appreciate any help/thoughts to get this corrected. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below and fix the margin and size as per your need

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" applyHtmlTag="true" >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <apex:slds />

    <apex:form>
        <div class="slds-box slds-size_1-of-6 slds-m-left_xx-large slds-m-top_large" >
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-3">
                    <span><input type="radio" name="radio"/> </span>
                    <span class="slds-m-left_small"> Option 1 </span>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                    <span><input type="text"/></span> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-m-top_small">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-3">
                    <span><input type="radio" name="radio"/> </span>
                    <span class="slds-m-left_small"> Option 2 </span>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                    <span><input type="text"/></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Avjit I think this is the only way we could do..if we use apex control, it's not properly formatting, I used above your example to get it working with few apex javascript function calls. Cheers!